# Make one or zero regex operator greedy

Tags: php, regex, greedy, regex-greedy, non-greedy

I have two sentences as input. Let's say for example:

```
<span>I love my red car.</span>
<span>I love my car.</span>
```

Now I want to match every textpart inside the span-tags AND if available the color.

If I use the following regex:

```
/<span>(.*?)(?P<color>red)(.*?)<\/span>/ms
```

Only the line with the color is matched. So I thought let's use ?-operator (for one or zero).

```
/<span>(.*?)(?P<color>red)?(.*?)<\/span>/ms
```

Now both lines/sentences will be matched. Sadly the color isn't matched anymore.

The question is why? By using ".*?" before the color part, I thought I had made the regex non-greedy, so that the color part would match, if it's existent. But as told, it doesn't...

Comment: Regex + markup go together like petrol and mules: though both useful, they don't work well together. Use `DOMDocument`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem here DOMDocument is not the point since matter is about parsing `I love my red car` string, which is just plain text.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo _"I want to match every textpart inside the span-tags"_ => Who's to say that the snippet provided isn't part of a bigger string of markup, containting div tags?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I think it's irrelevant, since the question is the same regardless of whether this is in HTML or not, as long as it's "something between two somethings".

Comment: What does this have to do with the 'one or zero' regex operator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first `(.*?)` will match between `>` and `I` and since it's lazy, it'll test the next part of the regex immediately: `(?P<color>red)?` but there's no `red` at that point, so the `0` option of `?` 'activates' and the regex continues to the next part, which is `(.*?)`. It'll again match the part between `>` and `I` and since it's lazy, it'll check the next part of the regex: `<\/span>` (I'm taking it as a whole).

So the second `(.*?)` will match all the way there.

Indeed, your `results[1]` will be null, as will be `results[color]` (I don't remember if you have to quote `color` or not) and `results[3]` will contain `I love my red car.`.

Hmm, one workaround is to use OR like NickC mentioned in his answer. Another you might use is by using a negative lookahead to check for each character:

```
<span>((?:(?!\bred\b).)*(?<colour>\bred\b)?.*)<\/span>
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/aU2vL3)

As a side note, I would advise using the word boundaries so that you don't match things like `reduce` or `jarred`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on why it doesn't work!  I do like my solution as it doesn't require double entry of the possible values :)

Comment: @NickC I was about to post something a bit like yours and then you posted your answer before I could; I just didn't want to have the same regex ^^;

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
/<span>(.*?(?P<color>red).*?|.*?)<\/span>/ms
```

Your original expression was pretty good.  I modified it slightly to make a new outer group match the whole sentence.  I used that new outer group to create an "or" condition to match "anything", in case the color is not present.

Abbreviated output:

```
Array
    [0] => Array
            [0] => <span>I love my red car.</span>
            [1] => <span>I love my car.</span>

    [1] => Array
            [0] => I love my red car.
            [1] => I love my car.

    [color] => Array
            [0] => red
            [1] =>
```